# Tags em uma tabela para cada?

Tags: mysql, query, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Eu tenho a tabela "noticia"e eu vou fazer um sistema de tags, essas tags terá que ter uma tabela para cada ou apenas uma tabela ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa de uma tabela para cada TAG, você cria somente uma outra tabela com as tags e o id da noticia conforme exemplo abaixo. Uma outra forma é criar uma coluna dentro da tabela de notícias onde você pode colocar as tags separadas por vírgula!

```
Noticia   | Tag
--------- | ------
Id        | Id
Desc      | IdNoticia
          | Tag
```

Comment: Eu tinha pensado em colocar dessa uma forma também, mas as tags serão cadastradas.

Comment: Quem irá cadastrar as tags?

Comment: Eu mesmo irei cadastrar.

Comment: Então você pode fazer o seguinte, criar uma tabela somente de TAGS! Dai se você precisar relacionar as tags com a noticia você pode ter uma tabela extra para unir as duas informações, tipo NoticiaTag, IdNoticia e IdTag, conseguiu entender?

Comment: sim intendi, assim é melhor, obrigado.